# How do the different media for No. 6 fit in with each other?

Tags: no.-6

During the Fall 2016 season, I chanced upon an off-hand comment somewhere on *Reddit* about the different adaptations of *No. 6*. If my memory serves me, the user argued that there was a discrepancy between the anime adaptation of *No. 6* and the original light novels in how a certain plot point (possibly a relationship between two characters) was approached.

Furthermore, at some point before that, I saw someone mention in passing that she disliked the anime adaptation but enjoyed the manga and light novel, which suggests to me in retrospect that there are notable differences between the different adaptations of the underlying content.

At the time, I did not pay heed to any of this, since I had no interest in *No. 6*. Unfortunately, over the last month or two, I have seen a couple stills from the *No. 6* manga that piqued my interest. Since I would like to know how to approach to series (via the manga, or via the anime) if I ever get to it, I am now wondering if there are any notable differences between the original light novels, the manga, and the anime, and if so, what the nature of these differences is:

- Are there major differences in *plot points*, similar to how there are differences in plot between the two different anime associated with *Fullmetal Alchemist* or between the anime and manga for *Elfen Lied*?
- Alternatively, are there obvious discrepancies with *framing* or *focus* or *tone*? (For instance, the *Revolutionary Girl Utena* manga feels more grounded in reality than the anime, and concepts such as "revolutionizing the world" are more clearly fleshed out there. However the *basic* structure of the manga matches that of the anime, although the anime has an expanded plot, pairs Juri with Shiori instead of Touga, etc.)

Comment: Sorry I didn't saw that. Then all I found was the differences between the novel and anime/manga here : http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/LightNovel/No6
As things like : "Lighter and Softer: The anime has taken out some of the more violent aspects of No. 6, especially character interactions and living conditions within the West Block."